# How to share google sheet macro in the same Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

How do I have a recorded macro available in all other google sheets that is in the same google drive ?

I follow the instructions on how to create a macro and I save it and test it and it works.

However, my use case is I will keep uploading the same sheet with the same format so it needs to be available to all sheets.

Comment: just an idea: deploy your macro as sicript and assign it to your sheets at https://script.google.com/home

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries

Comment: What is your macro doing? Depends on the way it works I believe the best way would be to create an Add-on for Sheets and use it on all your sheets, take a look at [the documentation for add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview) and tell us if it suits your needs.